# probability of obtaining palindrome in lottery

Tags: probability, statistics, palindrome

(Will describe it better later) The cristhmas lottery has been celebrated today in Spain. So I decided to calculate the probability of having a ticket with a palindrome number. The tickets have 5 numbers each from 1 to 9. I got 1,11%. Is my result right?

Comment: sharing your working could attract more positive responses.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I know but I'm so bad at english

Comment: Give it a try. so far I can read your english. Also, we share common notations for numbers =).

Comment: How did you get $\frac 1{90}$?  Seems to me there are $9^5$ lottery numbers and $9^3$ palindromes.  Are you excluding some lottery numbers?

Comment: Actually the Chistmas lottery tickets have numbers that include $0$, including leading $0$s.  The winning number today (22/12/2018) for a notional €4m prize was $03347$

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 9 digits and 5 numbers, the total number of possibilities is $9^5$

For a palindrome, there are 9 options for the first digit, 9 options for the second digit, 9 options for the third digit and 1 option for the last two. So there are $9^3$ palindromes.

So the probability is $\frac{9^3}{9^5}*100 = \frac{100}{9^2} = 1.23$% $(2dp)$

So no, 1.11% is not correct.